# Formatting change according to expiry date

Tags: excel

Is this even possible and if it is, what would be the best way to go about it?

What I'm trying to do?
I've been trying to setup a database of documents in Excel (name of document with a hyperlink to a folder structure where it is saved) along with their dates of issuing, time period for which they are valid and their expiry date - each in its own column.

For example, a date of issue for Document_001 is 21-02-2015, it is valid for one year, so its expiry date is 21-02-2016. That part is solved.

Now, these documents are certificates of a certain kind, and they are issued upon inspection completeness, which takes some time to organize and prepare. That's why in the fourth column I have a date which is 3 months before the date of expiry. So, for Document_001 that would be 21-11-2014.

***Now the part which I cannot figure out; is there a way to make Excel compare the dates in this column with the current one (TODAY()) and change the colouring of the cells which are past it?***

Comment: `=A1<Today()` for conditional formating (change A1 to the cell with the expiry date)... it will be true if it is in the past...

Answer (score 0):

If you had the 'warning date' in cell D1 (for example), you can add the following formula in another column:

`=today()-D1`

If you format this cell as a number, this will give the number of days between today and the warning date.  This number will be positive if today is before the warning date and negative if the warning date has passed (or zero if the warning date is today).

You can then use conditional excel formatting, and then format the cell, for example, in red if the cell value is negative.  Conditional formatting is slightly different on older versions of Excel, but there is an overview [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)